# ionic - where to write the methods called in <ion-menu> in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, menu

where to write the functions that are called by `<ion-menu>` in app.html.

i tried adding it to main.ts.

IS IT POSSIBLE TO GIVE MENU TO ONLY A PARTICULAR PAGE ONLY?

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)">
              Home
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(friendsPage)">
              Friends
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(eventsPage)">
              Events
            </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="closeMenu()">
              Close Menu
            </button>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>

      <ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: Check out the docs for `MenuController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are displaying the menu in `app.html` is correct one. The menu will be displayed in all pages. You should write the methods for that in `app.component.ts` file.

For more details on Menu in ionic, you can refer to the [Ionic MenuController Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/3.0.1/api/components/menu/MenuController/)